# Laravel: Show or hide content depending on a Session variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm doing a view that has a password protection. Basically when you access that resource, you have a view that indicates that you need to put a password. 
The correct behavior of this should be

1. You access the View
2. The user enters the password and sends the POST form
3. If the method redirects back with certain value, you must see the real content of the page.

So my blade code is the following:

```
@if ($passedPassword = Session::get('passedPassword'))
    ...here goes the real/true view content
@else
    <section class="questionnaire-questions">

      <div>

        <form
          action="{{ route('questionnaire.password', ['questionnaire' => $questionnaire->id]) }}"
          method="POST">
          {{ csrf_field() }}

          <h3 class="text-center">@lang('questionnaire.password.advice')<h3>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
              <div class="goal-input-group numeric">
                <label>PASSWORD</label>
                <input
                  style='visibility: visible;'
                  name="password"
                  type="password"
                >
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="goal-btn goal-btn-lg goal-btn-artic-blue">@lang('questionnaire.password')</button>
          </div>

        </form>

      </div>

    </section>  
@endif
```

That view is rendered with the following method:

```
public function show(Questionnaire $questionnaire) {

    $data = [];
    $data['questionnaire'] = $questionnaire;

    \Session::flash('passedPassword', false);
    return view('questionnaires.show', array('data' => $data));

}
```

In the previous method I'm passing the `passedPassword`, but I can't find a way to pass it as a flash variable. If there is a way to add data like

```
    return back()->with(array(
        'passedPassword' => false
    ));
```

But using the view method I'll really appreciate to know how.

Then, when the user clics the button I call the next function:

```
public function password(Request $request, Questionnaire $questionnaire) {
    if (strcmp($questionnaire->password, $request->input('password')) == 0) {
        return back()->with(array(
            'passedPassword' => false
        ));
    }
}
```

But even when the password is correct, I got the password view, the flash/session variable never arrived to the view.

Is there something I'm missing or doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The session variable is `false`. One should expect the `@else` branch of the view logic to always be executed. You can flash a `truthy` value for the variable instead

Comment: `passedPassword` is always `false` because you're overwriting it right before you call the view.

Comment: Yes I need that because sometimes the view can have the password and sometimes not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Dan told me in the comments, I was setting to false the value of the session variable.
So first I remove the `\Session::flash('passedPassword', false);` during the show method.

Then I modify my blade logic. In my case sometimes the password is needed and sometimes not.

```
@if (($passwordLength === 0) || ($passwordLength !== 0 && Session::has('passedPassword')))
```

With that, If the resource has no password we let the user pass. Or in the case it has a password and also we have the passedPassword variable, we also let the user see the content.